# How to encode the .apk file in android

Tags: android, obfuscation

here i need to safe my apk file from others to getting source codes for security purpose. Currently i need to release my apk file in both android market and other market in the web. So pls help me how to protect and encode apk file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: from unauthorized users. here i getting source code from some apk file. so i need to secure my apk file to avoid getting source code. How to do that.

Comment: Proguard makes it a lot harder, as suggested. There is NO bullet proof way to guard against reverse engineering, but ProGuard makes it really difficult.

Answer (score 5):

Use ProGuard as detailed on Android Developer site: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

This will obfuscate and compress your code, making it harder (but not impossible!) to reverse-engineer it.

Note that you'll likely have to mess with `-keep` options in `proguard.cfg` file to make sure your app still works after obfuscation.